# How to get all Object from Json to List

Tags: c#, json, windows, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I've Json codes from Xenforo getNodes API :

I'm using NewtonSoft Json for deserialize to List but i don't known how to define class for this json

I hope can get help from everyone

```
 {
  "count": 1,
  "nodes": {
    "1": {
      "node_id": 1,
      "title": "Main Category",
      "description": "",
      "node_name": null,
      "node_type_id": "Category",
      "parent_node_id": 0,
      "display_order": 1,
      "display_in_list": 1,
      "lft": 1,
      "rgt": 4,
      "depth": 0,
      "style_id": 0,
      "effective_style_id": 0
    },

  }
}
```

Because count can be dynamic change from Xenforo API when you create new Nodes so i don't known how to do that...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The innermost JSON object maps to a straightforward C# object, call it `Node`; you can use http://json2csharp.com/ to generate this class for you.   The `"nodes"` object looks have a variable set of properties whose names are lookup key and whose values are the previously defined `Node`.  All this is then contained in a root object.

Thus:

```
public class Node
{
    public int node_id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public object node_name { get; set; }
    public string node_type_id { get; set; }
    public int parent_node_id { get; set; }
    public int display_order { get; set; }
    public int display_in_list { get; set; }
    public int lft { get; set; }
    public int rgt { get; set; }
    public int depth { get; set; }
    public int style_id { get; set; }
    public int effective_style_id { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Node> nodes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ... I'm using Windows.DAta.Json and complex with Json.net then be ok ! I'll try your solution :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API document](https://github.com/Contex/XenAPI/wiki/REST-API-Actions#getNodes), the "nodes" element is not a standard json array format so you might want to use a custom `JsonConverter` like this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class NodesConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(Node[]);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var nodes = new List<Node>();

        foreach (JProperty property in serializer.Deserialize<JObject>(reader).Properties())
        {
            var node = property.Value.ToObject<Node>();
            // parse names as node_number
            node.node_number = int.Parse(property.Name);
            nodes.Add(node);
        }

        return nodes.ToArray();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
    }
}
```

Then you can deserialize the json text as follows:

```
public class XenNode
{
    public int count { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(NodesConverter))]
    public Node[] Nodes { get; set; }
}
public class Node
{
    public int node_number { get; set; }
    public int node_id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string node_name { get; set; }
    public string node_type_id { get; set; }
    public int parent_node_id { get; set; }
    public int display_order { get; set; }
    public int display_in_list { get; set; }
    public int lft { get; set; }
    public int rgt { get; set; }
    public int depth { get; set; }
    public int style_id { get; set; }
    public int effective_style_id { get; set; }
}

// Deserialize
XenNode xenNode = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<XenNode>(json);
```